# How to add 'tee' functionality to 'subprocess.call' in python

Tags: tee

I am newbie to Python programming,

`proc = subprocess.call([(app_path + exe_file),(app_path + config_file)],stdout = output_File)`

Above subprocess.call taking the executable bin file and respective configurations from the given path and working fine. But its not giving any trace info on output console (Ubuntu).

I need to add tee functionality, Means it should show the output on console as well as save the output to output_File also.

Comment: Is that a quote from the documentation? or your own source?

Comment: its from my own source

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `output_file` is a file object opened with `open('...', 'w')`. <s>You do need a stream object, which dispatches your `write` call to multiple output streams.</s> The stdin and stdout arguments need to be real files with a `fileno()` function.

I think it is pretty simple, if you call the function wait and then write it out:

```
import subprocess
import sys

file_out = open('mylog.txt', 'wb')

result_string = subprocess.check_output(['echo', 'hello'], shell=True)
print(result_string)
file_out.write(result_string)
```

Comment: `output_file = open( log.txt","wb")
proc = subprocess.call([(app_path + exe_file),(path + config_file)])
result_string = subprocess.check_output(['echo' ,'hello'],shell =True)
print(result_string)
output_file.write(result_string)`

After adding this code, able to print echo to the console. But no output stored in output_file.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output and try to understand the code.